# In magit, the log '-s' option shows ESCAPE characters instead of changing the color of the selected text

Tags: magit

Here is an example of a copy of the output of the magit log output with `-s` with the actual names omitted. (The ESC character precedes each of the [31 and [32 sequences in the following example in the Emacs output.)

```
b1fe5d2 Ignore files in the template

Author:    omit
Committer: omit


 .gitignore | 142 [32m+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++[m[31m--[m
 1 file changed, 138 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

**Update 2020-07-01**

My `~/.gitconfig` file had

```
[color]
    ui = true
```

as surmised by @phils

After the change to ui = auto, the colors in the diff stats are properly drawn, even when I add show graph in color `-c` flag as well.

Comment: Do you perhaps have `[color] ui = always` set in your git config?  If so, then use `auto` instead of `always` so that git can choose sensibly.  You never want to be telling git to include ansi colour escape codes in the output it's passing to Magit.

Answer (score 1):

Note Well:

If @phils would like to post an answer I would be happy to delete this one. Let me know by tomorrow.

As @phils suggested in the comments to the OP, the problem was solved by using the following in the `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

The problem was caused by the following stanza in the `~/.gitconfig` file

```
color
    ui = true
```